# Почему не видит класс с пространством имён?

Tags: php, ооп, namespace

Ошибка: Fatal error: Class 'Model\PDO' not found in ... on line 17
Код:

```
namespace Model;
class DB
{
    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db;charset=$this->charset";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
```

И чуть ниже есть строчка:

```
try {
    $this->DBconnect = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $opt);
}
```

17 строка это `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,`

И всё. Я с пространствами имён мало работал, туплю и не понимаю ка кпочинить. Пробовал `\Model\` поставить спереди везде - не помогло. Ошибка 100% связана с пространствами имён т.к. есть этот же код без них - всё работет.

Comment: Потому, что надо либо `use PDO;`, либо `new \PDO(...);`

Comment: @rjhdby поставил `new \PDO` и всё заработало, но каааак, что это за магия произошла? И если делать `use PDO;` где его правильно писать в этом случае? Вверху сразу после `namespace Model;` или внутри класса, т.е. после `class DB`?

Comment: `use` писать после `namespace`. дело в том, что `PDO` - это класс с пространством имен `\ `. Т.е. его полное имя `\PDO`.

Comment: @rjhdby понял, но не понял как и почему )) вынесите в ответ что ли...

Comment: Немного про неймспейсы http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Про `use` http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PDO` является классом в пространстве имен `\`("корневое" пространство имен), соответственно его полное имя `\PDO`.

У вас в самом начале задается пространство имен

```
namespace Model;
```

Соответственно когда вы пишете `new PDO(...)`, то ищется класс `new \Model\PDO(...)`, которого нет.

Собственно нужно либо использовать полное имя класса `new \PDO(...);`, либо вставить после задания текущего пространства имен `use PDO;`

**UPD**

Т.е. фактически конструкция `namespace My\Space;` означает, что все дальнейшие классы, будут интерпретироваться как классы в пространстве имен `\My\Space`, пока вы не переопределите текущее пространство имен каким нибудь другим.

Т.е.

```
namespace A;
class A{
    function __construct(){
        $b = new B();
        $c = new \C();
        $d = new D\D();
        $e = new \E\E();
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

Фактически же классы будут интерпретироваться так:

```
$a = new \A\A();
$b = new \A\B();
$c = new \C();
$d = new \A\D\D();
$e = new \E\E();
```

**UPD2**

Т.е. простыми словами, если первым символом в имени класса стоит `\` - это "абсолютный путь", если же этого символа нет - это "относительный" путь. А конструкция `use` говорит, что конкретный класс следует искать по указанному пути.